# How do I create a symlink from my app bin to /usr/bin?

Tags: deb, packaging, electron

So I have a deb package built using `electron-installer-debian`. When I `sudo dpkg -i app.deb`, it's unpacked in `/usr/lib/myapp/myappbin` and there's no symbolic link created. How do make it so the symbolic link is automatically created on installation?

Comment: Add commands to your `postinst` to that effect.

Comment: pls elaborate I don't understand

Comment: See https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-maintscripts and https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html to know what maintainer scripts are.

Comment: @adredx Did you get to work? If not please add more details how you are packaging it? are you using any specific helper tool?